# AWS S3 static website hosting with CloudFront and directory redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

My problem is not only hosting a static website on S3, it goes a bit further than that.

My plan is to have a www.foo.com on the S3.

So I create a bucket called `www.foo.com` and I set the domain to point there.

So every single file I have on my bucket is public, and is part of the website.

But there is one exception:

- Whenever I navigate to `www.foo.com/blog`, I want to make an internal redirection to the blog hosted on an EC2 container.

That would be easily achievable by using Nginx with a `proxy_pass` definition. But S3 is not Nginx.

I know there are some redirection rules I can apply, but how would I go for doing an internal redirection where for the user the URL is http://www.foo.com/blog but the blog is stored on a different machine.

Comment: You have a tag `amazon-cloudfront` but you didn't mention if you are using it?

Comment: I will be using CloudFront for serving the S3 assets.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned you are using CloudFront, you want to use that for the redirection instead of S3. You would configure two origins in your CloudFront distribution, your S3 bucket and your EC2 server. You would configure S3 as your default origin, and create a cache behavior with the /blog pattern that points to the EC2 origin.

Comment: I tried to do that, bit it didn't work. I couldn't get to understand the CloudFront testing as for every setting I change I need to wait 2 hours for the propagation. Any thoughts @mark-b?

Answer (score 0):

The website is a pure static site??, not using vue.js, react.js, etc... in that case I think you'll need a javascript code to redirect, otherwise with a javacript framework you can easily redirect to another page... in cloudfront i knew is possible redirect from specific error number like 404, 303... etc.

;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34757810)